# How to get Cassini (and others) to always call Application_BeginRequest when requesting a URL?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, global-asax, cassini

I have a web application which uses a custom framework. It relies on getting an Application_BeginRequest to parse a URL and serve a proper page by `Response.Output`. Note it's a bit of an experiment and clearly not ASP.Net-MVC. It also does not use any modules or anything like that. The web.config is very minimal, and I hope to keep it that way.

It works fine on Apache+mod_mono and under mono's xsp implementation. My problem is trying to get it to work with .Net now. I remember it once working under Microsoft's Cassini  implementation, but I can't remember what configuration I had to do.

Right now, my problem is that I'll get a `BeginRequest` for say `/static/style.css`, and for custom routes like `/login`, but for some reason when I request `/` cassini will just display a list of files and I do not get a `BeginRequest`

How do I configure Cassini  so that it will always call `BeginRequest`? Also, bonus points for a solution that works for IIS as well. (I haven't tried IIS, but I'd expect it to have similar problems)

Comment: Do you have a Global.asax file? That's usually where BeginRequest is handled.

Comment: @Icarus yes. I have it, and when debugging, I put a breakpoint on BeginRequest. I hit it for nearly every request except for `/`

Comment: this is a very old question, but, does this attemp was on a WCF service? It might be your problem. WCF needs to be configured in a different way